# Can enemies see the light from an aimed flamethrower?

Tags: alien-isolation

In *Alien: Isolation*, when aiming the flamethrower, a nice little flame starts that doesn’t use fuel but makes a pretty bright light. **Will it alert enemies if they see this flame, like the flashlight does?**

Comment: As far as I could tell, no... but I don't have a definitive answer.